# Curl function not working, but get content file yes?

Tags: php

i am testing an php api that worked with the file get content, but i need it with the curl funcion but its not working, and i dont have error on php, this is the code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$fist = $_GET["url"];
$Url = "https://api.apisecret.co/1/remotedl/add?login=LoginData&key=PasswordData&url=".$fist;


function url_get_contents ($Url) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}



?>
```

Comment: `$Url = "SECRETAPILINK&=$fist";` - sure that's the complete correct url (and I don't mean the SECRET part)?

Comment: i have another url but have my password and secret username, tested on file get and its working idk why ;(

Comment: Shouldn't it be $Url = "SECRETAPILINK&=".$fist;

Comment: tried, still without working